# How do i get the row of a widget in a tablewidget in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a TableWidget with ComboBoxes created by pressing a button. I need to get the row of a ComboBox if I interact with is so another CombobBox changes its contents. I found the [this](https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_get_hold_of_a_cell_widgets_row) but I can't understand it fully.

```
#include <QtGui>

class TableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  TableWidget()
  {
    edit = new QLineEdit(this);
    setColumnCount(5);
    setRowCount(5);
    setCellWidget(4,1, edit);
    connect(edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString)), this, SLOT(test1(const QString)));
  }
public slots:
void test1(const QString &text)
{
  QWidget *wid = QApplication::focusWidget();
  if (wid) {
    QModelIndex index = indexAt(wid->pos());
    qDebug() << index.row();
  }
}

private:
  QLineEdit *edit;

};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  TableWidget window;
  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Trying to write the above in python, i have this:

```
current_widget = QApplication.focusWidget()
>> <PyQt4.QtGui.QComboBox object at 0x0226DDB0>
```

How do i use the above in the IndexAt function ?

I am using QtDesigner.The following is my table:

```
    self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(Dialog)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 521, 91))
    self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);"))
    self.tableWidget.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
    self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(False)
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
```

And this how i insert the comboBox widget and insert the items in want:

```
index = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
criteria1_comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.tableWidget)
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setPointSize(10)
criteria1_comboBox.setFont(font)

for combo_ind,i in enumerate(["Name", "Extension", "Size"]):
    criteria1_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    criteria1_comboBox.setItemText(combo_ind, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", i, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))     
self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(index, 0, criteria1_comboBox)
```

Comment: Don't look up the C++ Qt documentation, use the PyQt documentation.

Comment: please show the definition of `index`

Comment: index = self.tableWidget.rowCount()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `QTableWidgetItem` instance, you can just use its `row` field. See the documentation [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#row).

Comment: Could you show the part(s) of your code where you make the TableWidget and where you try to access it?

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Junuxx pointed out.

The code you have posted could be used where given you had a widget, a ComboBox, whose position on the Table(in terms of `row` and `column`) the program was unaware of, and you wanted to find out the `QModelIndex`(from which you could get the `row`), on the TableWidget, where it could have been positioned.

The `indexAt` function returns the `QModelIndex` using the position coordinates(in pixels) it is provided, in the case of your code the `QLineEdit`, but could be a QComboBox`or any`QWidget` as well.

But do heed both Junuxx's comment and answer.